# Looping over 3D array in parallel.for

Tags: c#, multithreading, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing

I have a 3D array with arbitrary X, Y and Z lengths
I want to iterate over it in a parallel.for loop, which can't be nested without wasting tasks afaik
Instead, the single loop's length is ArrayLengthX * ArrayLengthY * ArrayLengthZ

Can I mathematically get the current 3D array element from the current iteration + the X, Y and Z length of the array? if so how?

edit : Example below, hope this is enough to understand what's going on

```
DimensionSettings dimensionSettings = dimension.Settings;
    Vector3Int DimSize = dimensionSettings.GetDimensionSize();

    TaskProgressMutex.WaitOne();
    CurrentProgress = 0;
    TotalProgress = DimSize.x * DimSize.y * DimSize.z;
    TaskProgressMutex.ReleaseMutex();

    int ChunkAmount = DimSize.x * DimSize.y * DimSize.z;
    GD.Print("Chunks to generate : " + ChunkAmount);

    ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, ChunkAmount, (int i) =>
    {
        GD.Print(i);
        int xcoords = ???;

        int ycoords = ???;

        int zcoords = ???;


        Vector3Int ChunkCoords = new Vector3Int(xcoords, ycoords, zcoords);
        GD.Print("Current Chunk : " + xcoords + " " + ycoords + " " + zcoords);

        GenerateChunk(ChunkCoords, seed);

        TaskProgressMutex.WaitOne();
        CurrentProgress += 1;
        //GD.Print("Chunk " + xcoords + " " + ycoords + " " + zcoords + " finished generating. Current Progress : " + CurrentProgress);
        TaskProgressMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    });
```

Comment: By the way, its inefficient to use `Parallel.`xxx with synchronisation objects like mutexs.  Best to partition your data so that locks are not required.

Comment: I need those mutex because they're modifying an int that's used to track progress of how many chunks are generated, which I then divide by the total amount of chunk to display the progress as a % in a progress bar
if 2 tasks modify the int at the same time or the code updating the progress bar reads it while it's being modified it's gonna cause issues I think

Comment: The _last_ thing you want to do with `Parallel.`xxx is to _display progress_ in a GUI. That defeats the whole purpose

Comment: I'm starting parallel.for from a task though, the main thread still runs while all the tasks started by parallel.for run. It's said tasks's progress I'm tracking

Comment: I ended up making a nested loop before my parallel.for where I create an array of 3D coords, which I then use in the parallel.for
I also tried removing the taskprogressmutex locking/unlocking and the currentprogress incrementation and it runs almost exactly as fast

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to parallelize only the outer loop (the X dimension), and do normal (non-parallel) inner loops for the Y and Z dimensions:

```
ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};
Parallel.For(0, dimSize.X, options, (int x) =>
{
    for (int y = 0; y < dimSize.Y; y++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < dimSize.Z; z++)
        {
            Vector3Int chunkCoords = new (x, y, z);
            GenerateChunk(chunkCoords, seed);
        }
    }
});
```

The idea is to increase the chunkiness of the parallel work. In general the more chunky is the workload, the less is the overall overhead of the parallelization. At the other extreme, if each unit of work is too chunky, the partitioning of the work may become imbalanced.

Also when you use the `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach`/`Parallel.Invoke` methods I am suggesting to specify always the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism), although this suggestion [deviates from the general advice](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72981) offered in the official documentation.